# Action fantasy manhwa where the female lead pretended to be a boy to go and spy on the duke

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

This was a manhwa I read long ago and I can't remember the title.

The main character is a girl with red hair and her boss (crown prince with long blonde hair) ordered her to spy on the duke.

In the first chapter, she had to cut her hair and she also drinks a potion to deepen her voice. The antagonist is... crazy. He has blue/cyan, medium hair. And he does human experiments with *Mythril*. He was also a result of an experiment (I think?).

The antagonist and the male lead (duke) know each other and have a bad relationship. There was a lot of actions here. The scenes I remembered are: one time the female lead got kidnapped, the antagonist threatened the king for *Mythril*, the antagonist made the female lead drink a truth serum blah blah, the antagonist and the male lead (duke) fought on a cliff then backstory. The last chapter was the female lead and the male lead getting married.

And by the way, this was released about 2019-2021 (completed).

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[The Duke's Servant](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-dukes-servant)***...?

> Lindsay is a top-secret spy about to take on her most difficult mission yet: to disguise herself as a man?! Her target is the Duke. Rich, mysterious, and… an infamous womanizer. Cutting her hair, drinking elixirs to hide her voice, as a servant she must infiltrate his manor and investigate the mysterious disappearance of lords and ladies in the area. However, when she meets the Duke for the first time and he kisses her, is it her identity that's compromised or her heart…
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Duke's Servant."]

The protagonist, Lindsay Asbel, is a 20-year-old, red-headed spy who works for Euthigen, a crown prince with long blond hair who freed her from slavery when she was a child and took her in.

After rescuing a princess from some alchemists, she's told that her next mission will be to infiltrate the home of Duke Fian De Lecapullone -- the male lead of the story, pictured above with Lindsay -- and spy on him. To her annoyance, though, she's ordered to pose as a lord-in-waiting rather than a lady-in-waiting. In preparation for the mission, she cuts her hair short and drinks a potion to alter her voice.

The primary antagonist of the story is Leonard, a blue-haired alchemist whose experiments with mithril have enabled him to live for centuries. In chapter 67, he kidnaps Lindsay. In chapter 69, he and Fian have a swordfight on a cliff over Lindsay's fate. And in chapter 80, he coerces King Calvas into acquiring more mithril for him, threatening to use his son, Euthigen, as one of his test subjects if he doesn't.

In the final chapter, Lindsay and Fian attend the wedding of another couple and promise to spend the rest of their lives together.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/thedukesservant/info).